# ASP.net parent-child traversal using clientID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am new to ASP.net and had been googling around for days for the below question but have yet to solve this question.

**Background**

I would like to retrieve the parent ID using the child's client ID in order to append the element tag of the retrieved ID using JQuery. However, I am getting undefined value for the below code and still could not resolved it. Any experts here who can advise on how I should edit my code in order to get the parent's attribute id? Thanks.

```
    var clientID = <%= btnRemoveFromCart.ClientID %> ;
    var parentID =$("#clientID").parent().attr('id');
    var imageID = $('#parentID').children(".single-products").children('.productinfo text-center').children('.image').attr('id');
    var wordID = $('#parentID').children(".single-products").children('.productinfo text-center').children('.word').attr('id');
    var logoID = $('#parentID').children(".single-products").children('.productinfo text-center').children('.h2').children('.logo').attr('id');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fashion-grid1">                                                                                             
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lsvDataSet" DataSource='<%# Eval("Value") %>' OnItemCommand="lsvDataSet_ItemCommand">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 product-image-wrapper padding-bottom" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 25px;">
            <div class="single-products">
               <div class="productinfo text-center">
                   <img src='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' alt="" class="image" />
                   <h2 class="h2"><span class="logo"><%# Eval("Tag") %></span></h2>
                   <div class="word"><%# Eval("Name") %></div>
               </div>
```

Just to add on, is it possible to also advise on what method i could use such as .value or .text to call the client ID element tag in order to use JQuery to append to the HTML? Really grateful to the community here.

Comment: I know you have resolved this yourself, but the HTML code you have provided is missing `btnRemoveFromCart`, which seems to be a vital element of your javacript. Your code is also incompleter in that there is no closing `ItemTemplate` tag. It is hard to work out how to work with you document stucture of you don't provide the complete **relevant** structure(s).

Comment: Thanks Jon for the feedback. Greatly appreciate your help. Will bear that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I solved the problem using siblings and eq. Below is my code.Hope it helps others.

```
 var imageID = $(<%= btnRemoveFromCart.ClientID %>).parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings().children().children().attr('class');
 var logoID = $(<%= btnRemoveFromCart.ClientID %>).parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings().children().children().eq(1).children().attr('class');
 var wordID = $(<%= btnRemoveFromCart.ClientID %>).parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings().children().children().eq(2).attr('class');
```

Comment: This may work, but it would be very fragile in the future. Look at [Closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [Parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to search "up" the DOM and [Find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), to search "down" the DOM

Comment: Thanks Jon. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

Give your outermost div tag an id and try this:

```
parentID = $(".single-products").parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: Does clientID have a value? And if so, you have to make sure you have a child element that has that id.

Comment: Yes. clientID has a value.

Comment: Do you have an element in your DOM with id equal to it? Also does that element have a parent element?

Comment: Nope. No element in my dom with id equal to it. The element have a parent element but when i trace the ID, it is the right one.

Comment: You can use $(#idname) with element IDs only, if you want to select a class do $(.classname)

Comment: Right. Thanks Lucas.